# is it possible to save voice memos into ipod lib?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'd like to know whether it's possible to record a voice memo and save it directly in an `ipod` lib playlist (say called `voicememo_playlist`) ?
If so, can someone provide pointers?
I'd like to have a single interface to load music and voice memos, which is the `ipod` lib playlist (using the `MPMediapickercontroller` below)

Please help.

```
 MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAny];
    mediaPicker.delegate = self;
    mediaPicker.prompt = @"Select Audio";
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;

    [self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Not an Xcode question. -- It's not possible using official APIs, but if you can use private frameworks then [go ahead](http://github.com/libipodimport). And search before you ask -- this question is a duplicate.

Comment: well, I need to do using official Apple APIs.  But thanks for the suggestion.